# Alternative for gstreamer pulsesrc element in windows?

Tags: windows, gstreamer, wasapi

I have the following simple pipeline in linux, which I use to send output audio from a device to other.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! rtpopuspay ! udpsink port=$2 host=$1
```

How would I do the same on windows? What GStreamer element, can I use? I tried `wasapisrc` which only captured the mic audio and not the speaker. Can I fix this or is there another element altogether for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the `loopback` option in the `wasapisrc` element but it didn't work. I think the documentation is probably outdated.

What worked for me is, enabling Stereo Mix on Windows('https://thegeekpage.com/stereo-mix/') and using it as a source in `wasapisrc`

After enabling it, do `gst-device-monitor-1.0 Audio/Source` to get list of all the Audio input devices and under it there would be Stereo Mix, copy the `device.strid` of it and do `gst-launch-1.0 waspisrc device=$device.strid ! fakesink`.

This will capture the audio coming to speaker on windows, and you can do anything with it, streaming to other devices, recording or mixing or anything. Also the `low-latency` option to `wasapisrc` set to true brings a little improvement in latency too.